# Strophe MAM does not return messages after first run

Tags: javascript, ejabberd, strophe

I have written a function to get archived messages between two dates from ejabberd server. It returns messages when it first run but does not return any message after first run.
Here is my code:

```js
function getMessageHisttory(jid) {
    var end = otherUser.oldestMessageDate;

    var start = new Date();
    start.setDate(end.getDate() - 2);
    STROP.connection.mam.query($scope.selfIdUser, {
        "with": $scope.otherIdUser,
        "start": start.myFormat(),
        "end": end.myFormat(),
        onMessage: function (message) {
            console.log('Message: ', message);
            return true;
        },
        onComplete: function (response) {
            otherUser.oldestMessageDate = start;
            console.log("Completed");
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: It solved itself. One morning it was running normally. I had not change any code. I still don't know what was wrong.